# SQL mass replace column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with a table name called `mybb_users`.

All users have a field name called `avatar`. Some users have their avatar set as

```
 http://graph.facebook.com/userid/picture?width=250&height=250.
```

I want to mass-replace all the width and height of the people that use a facebook picture with this amount of width and height. I unfortunately don't know how to do this since the userid is random. Is there anyway I can mass replace `width=250&height=250` to `width=140&height=140` ?

Thank you!

Comment: Which RDBMS are we talking? MySQL?

Comment: Yes sorry, its MySQL :)

Comment: What you're looking for is the string function [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with the `REPLACE` function:

```
UPDATE mybb_users
SET avatar = REPLACE(`avatar`, 'width=250&height=250', 'width=140&height=140')
WHERE avatar like '%graph.facebook%'
```

for further information have a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: Thank you for the quick respond, will this only overwrite that certain part?

Comment: yes. it only replaces `width=250&height=250` with `width=140&height=140` in the `avatar` column

Comment: Awesome it worked, thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can update just the portion you want like this:

```
UPDATE mybb_users SET avatar = REPLACE(avatar, 'width=250&height=250', 'width=140&height=140')
```

this should replace all occurences of the 250 with 140